# Parse Local Datastore e Message "no results found for query"

Tags: parse-platform, local, datastore

I am trying to finish this program and i am stuck.  This is my first program and now it wont work.  I keep getting this error when i add  query.fromLocalDatastore();   The code runs fine until i try to get it from the local storage.  This is telling me there is nothing there for it to retrieve and i don't know why.  When i added my test data it worked fine but when i try to pull data from another table i get the error above.  Apparently when i added the test data the server synced with the local datastore.  Now it is not.  Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

```
           public class DataHolder extends Application {
                int age;

                @Override
                public void onCreate() {
                    super.onCreate();
                    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(getApplicationContext());
                    Parse.initialize(this,key, key);
                    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
                    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
                    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
                }


      public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements Disclaimer.DisclaimerListener {  
     protected void continueToRun() {     
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int x, long lng) {
                    final ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Phone_Numbers");
                    query.fromLocalDatastore();
                    if (x == 1) {
                        final Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Protocol_Template.class);
                        query.fromLocalDatastore();
                        query.whereEqualTo("objectId", "uGANULyrdL");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

    }

        public class Protocol_Template extends Activity {
            DataHolder global;


            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_protocol__template);

                final TextView protocol = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt02);
             findViewById(R.id.btn2timesUpperLeft);

                final ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Phone_Numbers");

                query.fromLocalDatastore();

                query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            final String protocols = object.get("PhoneNumber").toString();

                            protocol.setText(protocols);

                        } else {
                            protocol.setText(e.getMessage());

                        }
                                               }
                                           });
            }
```

Comment: Where are you "pinning" the objects. You need to pin objects before looking at them in the local storage.

Comment: Yes.  this worked.  thank you  :)